# What's the use of URL param in Routes to controller-actions which only handle AJAX request and return response (no view shown in browser)?

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I am learning Laravel v6. I have a view, say `addpainting.blade.php` from where we let users enter details of new paintings into DB. Right after user enters title of painting, an *`POST`* `AJAX` request (from JQuery script in that view) goes to an action `BookController@checkIfRecordExists()` which returns `true` if that painting's record already exists in db, in which case we redirect the user to another view where he can *edit* the record already present in DB.

Likewise in the same view there is a button which sends another `Jquery AJAX POST` request to another controller action to do something else on the server.

And then another button on the same page which sends another `JQuery AJAX POST` request to the server to yet another controller action to perform yet another task.

**Question:**

In the `routes/web.php`, intuitively thinking, I should not have to specify a URL in my route, as this URL is not that of a web page and will never be opened in the browser. The only parts of the route which are ever used (in my understanding) are the second parameter of the `Route::method(URL, Action)->name()` function and also the name we give to the route, as we'll use it in `{{ route('nameOfRoute') }}` for the value of `url` parameter of `$.ajax()` request in JQuery.

```
Route::post('Supposed/URL???', AJAXController@actionName)->name("nameOfRoute");
```

1. Is it really necessary to specify routes for AJAX requests? Or are routes for views only, i.e. a route for each view to be displayed in browser?
2. If there are multiple POST AJAX requests going to different methods/actions of the same controller, then shall I give the same URL to all those routes? e.g. `Route::post('cat/star', AJAXController@actionName)->name("nameOfRoute");`, `Route::post('cat/star', AJAXController@anotherActionName)->name("anotherNameOfRoute");` and `Route::post('cat/star', AJAXController@yetAnotherActionName)->name("yetAnotherNameOfRoute");`
3. How would I even know what name/string to give to the URL for such a route? For example when I write URL for a page the user is going to see in browser, I'll write a descriptive URL which I want the user to see in his/her address bar. e.g. `Route::get('paintings/dashboard', PaintingsController@displayPaintingsDashboard)->name('paintings.dashboard')`. But what is the use of this particular URL for a route for controller action handling an ajax request and returning a response?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that AJAX is involved, otherwise you could indeed do without URLs though it might get ugly. AJAX however, requires a URL to work, as the URL is a standardised web address. This goes way back to the creation of the WWW as we use it today, and that history is interesting to learn, but not really the point.

So, specifically, to answer your questions:

1. Yes, it absolutely is necessary to have a URL for AJAX requests.
2. I mean, you could do that, but I don't see the point. Defining different routes for the same address would just result in the last defined route to be called.
3. Depends on the application. Usually, a web app either renders views (HTML format), returns an API response (JSON/XML/SOAP/what have you) or both or none. The point in separating routes is separation of concerns. You could technically have a single route that does everything, but that would defeat the purpose of a framework such as Laravel. You ideally want short, easy to read controller actions and keep things separate to help deal with constant requirements and business logic changes. So, bottom line, you want to give your actions meaningful names, that's the most important. The naming will probably change anyway as the application grows/changes, but try your best to describe WHAT the action is accomplishing.

If I can provide more input, let me know and I'll help.